# Compiling an xpath expression - has an invalid token

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am trying to compile an xpath expression that is made dynamically and receiving an exception that - "it has an invalid token".

```
text =  GetText(); // has this value: /root/Info/PublisherName1 = "abcd"
XPathResultType result = XPathExpression.Compile(text).ReturnType;
```

I have tried escaping the double quotes using the following code, but still receiving the same exception:

```
text = text.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
text = text.Replace("'", "\\'");
```

After trying to escape the quotes as above, the string still have the single quotes inside without showing any backslash when seen in the debugger.

How can this be done?

Comment: Oh no it isn't. It's valid in every version of XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/root/Info/PublisherName1 = "abcd"` is invalid XPath for methods from `System.Xml.XPath` namespace

I believe you are looking for something like this:
`/root/Info/PublisherName1[text() = "abcd"]`

Comment: This same string works inside a doc.CreateNavigator().Evalute(text); I just want to check if a condition's text is correct syntactically. I don't want to return a node set from the expression.

Comment: @teenup, anyway `/root/Info/PublisherName1 = "abcd"` is invalid XPath and won't be compiled

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But, is this a valid condition syntax in xpath? Is there a way I can dynamically check if the condition syntax is correct?

Comment: @teenup, as I wrote, the valid XPath is `/root/Info/PublisherName1[text() = "abcd"]`. I don't think there is a build-in .NET Framework method which checks condition validity specifically. The only way is to check the whole XPath using `XPathExpression.Compile` and catch `XPathException` if the query is invalid

Comment: @Kirill You are providing misinformation. The expression `/a/b/c = "abcd"` is a valid XPath expression. It returns a boolean. It's possible that this particular API will only handle XPath expressions that return a node-set, but that would be a specific product restriction.

Comment: @Kirill, XPath is defined by W3C, not by Microsoft. If this syntax doesn't work in .NET then that's a product restriction in the Microsoft implementation, it's not a limitation of the XPath language.

Answer (score 1):

The Expression is a valid XPath expression, the problem is the quotes are coming from a Microsoft Word file and we need to replace smart quotes with straight quotes as follows:

```
text = text.Replace('\u2018', '\'')
.Replace('\u2019', '\'')
.Replace('\u201c', '\"')
.Replace('\u201d', '\"')
.Replace('\u201e', '\"')
.Replace('\u2033', '\"');
```

Then, it works without any problem.

Sorry @Kirill, I have to deselect your answer.